# TFS4JIRA settings issue

Tags: tfs, jira, jira-plugin

what should i write in Synchronizer Application's External URL at TFS4JIRA settings?

and what should be its password?? Can anyone give me an example??

Comment: How did find Synchronizer  External URL & password and tfs4jira synchronize app need to be install all windows machine who using tfs?

Answer (score 0):

For free you would have to roll your own. I usually recomend TaskTop($).